# Changing toolbar size, enlarging icons in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, ckeditor

I want to enlarge CKEditor's icons to 32x32 pixels. I am working on it right now, taking one of the standard skins, changing all the dimensions, converting `buttons.png`'s offsets and hoping there are not too many side effects.

Before I spend half a day or more re-inventing the wheel: Does something like this already exist? I don't care about the icons as much as the CSS and Javascript groundwork. Converting that from 16 to 32 Pixels, and re-calculating offsets, heights, and sizes is the tedious work.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it manually. It is possible, but involves a lot of CSS work.

Comment: I would like to do something like this. I had hoped it would only be a few minor tweaks, but it didn't quite work out for me so I gave up and reverted back to the original. Which skin did you change and how much effort was required?

Comment: @Breadtruck it was a *lot* of work, at least a day and a half, and there was a lot of small fiddly things that needed changing. I used the standard skin. Sadly, I don't have the result any more, otherwise I would publish it here!